# How to get print support from airprint not enable printer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, airprint

I have [Posiflex](http://www.posiflex.com/english/01_products/02_detail.php?pid=92&xid=232) printer. As far as I know it is not AirPrint enabled. And also it doesn't have wifi also. What I need to do is connect to the printer and take print outs using my AirPrint enabled Application which is installed in my iPad (IOS 5).

I search the web but could not find any promising solution.

I find [xPrintServer](http://www.pcworld.com/article/248441/airprint_to_almost_any_printer.html) can be used to overcome my problem.
But unfortunately it doesn't [support](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/xprintserver/xprintserver-supported-printers.php) Posiflex printer.

Also there is another [solution](http://www.aramistech.com/tips-tricks/enable-airprint-in-windows-and-use-any-printer/) which need a PC also. Using that iPad can connect to the printer through the PC and PC need to be up and running to take print outs which is not acceptable. Can some one help met to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Such printers don't need any special drivers, you can make them easily by hand (define paper width, chars per line, etc). This printer uses Epson standard escape codes - ESC/POS. You need to learn how printing was done in old days when we used good dot matrix printers. As printer have ethernet port it allows you to send pure ascii text (plus some escape codes) to tcp/ip port and you will have it printed.

In [documentation](http://www.posiflex.com/upfiles/USPP8KA0.pdf) you will find:

> Any PC connected in same network can use TCP/IP to use PP-8000L in the way like a directly connected local printer. So, for direct I/O control by tools like “HyperTerminal” all commands applicable to the serial or parallel interface model can work on PP-8000L in the same way as PP-8000 except the port must be TCP/IP with the IP address of the printer.

Edit:
For ESC/POS you can use Epson high level API: http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm
I'm not sure if it will work with other ESC/POS compatible printers.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is not looking to write to the printer directly, but to use higher level APIs. Considering how POS-style printers work, using high-level APIs tends to result in abysmal performance.

Comment: @Petesh There is high level api made by Epson. I don't have such printer right now to test if this works with non-Epson printers too. Other manufacturers also provide high level API like Star, OKI, etc, but still they use ESC/POS.